# 404 while contacting web-service container (docker)

Tags: java, web-services, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build a docker application with 3 containers:

- troparo_app (web-service)
- library_app (web-client)
- troparo_db (postgres db)

Somehow, I am getting a 404 while trying to connect from the app to the webservice.

The webservice responds ok from host on:

http://localhost:8080/troparo_app/services

Tested it from SOAP UI and working just fine

for the web-client(library_app), I can't access the main page at:

http://localhost:8090/library-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/login

but then I get a 404:

```
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '404: null' when communicating with http://localhost:8080/troparo_app/services/connect/ConnectService
```

My docker-compose below:

```
# Version of docker-compose
version: '3'

services:
# getting postgres DB
db:
  image: postgres:11.1
#container_name: troparo_db
ports:
  - 5432:5432
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: ocp
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
  POSTGRES_DB: troparo
  POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: --data-checksums
  PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumes:
  - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
networks:
  - troparo

 # getting troparo image
 webservice:
 image: troparo_app
 container_name: troparo_app
 build: .
 ports:
 - 8080:8080
 depends_on:
  - db
 networks:
  - troparo


# getting troparo image
webapp:
image: library_app
container_name: library_app
build: ../webo/library/.
ports:
    - 8090:8080
depends_on:
  - webservice
networks:
  - troparo


volumes:  
pg-data:

networks:
troparo:
```

Dockerfile for library_app:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.14-jre8
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY ./library-web/target/library-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/library-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

Dockerfile for troparo_app:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.14-jre8
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY ./troparo-web/target/troparo_app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/troparo_app.war
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

I connected to the client container and ping the service -> ok
I tried several combination for connecting to the webservice:

```
http://troparo_app:8080

http://localhost:8080
```

but all fails so far.

I am new to docker so I imagine there is something I forgot to configure in the network but I couldn't figure it out so far so if anyone can help, I d be really grateful !!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some more thoughts / testing, I finally have it working!!

The webservice is simply accessible on http://webservice:8080

Comment: I simply replaced localhost (that can be used to connect to a container from the computer host) with the name of the container, here webservice (name I gave on the docker-compose) as those are in the same network.